# android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager cannot converted to android.app.FragmentManager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm a fresher in Android,I try to use fragment in tablet.But I'm experiencing error in my MainActivity.java file.

The error shows that it need 'android.app.FragmentManager' not 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager'.I have checked the library,it were imported by Android Studio automatically.

How can I fix it?Thanks a lot!

```
package com.example.fragmenttest;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        replaceFragment(new RightFragment());
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.button:
                replaceFragment(new AnotherRightFragment());
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.right_fragment,fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change
`import android.app.Fragment;`
to 
`import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;`

Comment: Ops,the outcome is same as MichaelStoddart's.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

to:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

Comment: Sorry,it doesn't work.It adds two new errors in 'new RightFragment()' and 'new AnotherRightFragment()'.

Comment: These new errors could be because RightFragment and AnotherRightFragment (I suggest better naming conventions) are using android.app.Fragment; instead of android.support.v4.app.Fragment; change this in all fragments and it should work @RealCR1

Answer (score 0):

You may need to include the support v4 library in the build/gradle

Comment: I've tried your suggestion,but it doesn't work well.